# How can I access function in ChildComponent from another ChildComponent in .NET Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor

I have looked thru google and only found solutions for when you can reach functions/values from child to parent and the other way around but not from chil to child.

Parent Component, container for child components

```
 //PARENT 
<h3>ParentComponent</h3>
<Child_1_Component></Child_1_Component>

<Child_2_Component></Child_2_Component>

<h3>Child_1_Component</h3>
```

### CHILD 1 User puts in something

```
//CHILD 1
<h1>User puts in something</h1>
<input type="text"/>
<button @onclick="@(() => getValue(10))"></button>

@code {
    List<WhatEver> whatEvers = new List<WhatEver>();

    public void getValue(int value)
    {
        var message = "something";
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            var whatever = new WhatEver();
            whatever.Name = message;
            whatEvers.Add(whatever);
        }
        //Sends value to Service
    }
}
```

CHILD 2 Displays via Service what the user put in Child 1 and gives the user posibility to change the value.

### And Here I want to be able to reach the function in child 1

```
<h3>Child_2_Component</h3>
<h1>Displays Value from service and lets user put in new value</h1>
<input type="text" />
<button @onclick="@(() => getValue(10))"></button>

@*Here I want to use the funcction getValue(x) in Child_1_Component*@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Worker class and put the getValue(int value) in.

```
public class Worker{
    public object getValue(int value){
       //[...]
       return something;
    }
}
```

Then there are two possibilities:

**Solution 1**

Create an instance of Worker in the parent of both child items and put it to both childs.

```
//PARENT 
<h3>ParentComponent</h3>
<Child_1_Component Worker="@MyWorker"></Child_1_Component>
<Child_2_Component Worker="@MyWorker"></Child_2_Component>

<h3>Child_1_Component</h3>

@code {
    private Worker MyWorker{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
       MyWorker = new Worker();   
    }
}
```

And then the Child, where Worker is same object in both childs:

```
//CHILD 1
<h1>User puts in something</h1>
<input type="text"/>
<button @onclick="@(() => Worker.getValue(10))"></button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Worker Worker { get; set; }        
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You move getValue(int value) into an Service and define it in Startup.cs, then also both childs have the same instance.

```
 //Startup.cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    [...]
    services.AddScoped<Worker>();
 }
```

And then the Child, where Worker is same object in both:

```
//CHILD 1
@inject Worker MyWorker
<h1>User puts in something</h1>
<input type="text"/>
<button @onclick="@(() => MyWorker.getValue(10))"></button>
```